# How to add a bot to contact list after removing it

Tags: c#, botframework

I believe I've found a bug in Skype for Windows 10. I was trying to test detecting add/remove bot from contacts. Once I removed the bot from contacts, the link to add the bot back stopped working. It only shows you the bot with a question mark next to it. I tried to follow these instructions for adding:

https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA421/how-do-i-manage-my-contacts-in-skype-for-windows-desktop#5

But when right clicking the name to add to contacts again, the expected option is missing. It also turns out that any message sent from my bot to myself while in this state will go missing. This had me believing my bot was not working for at least a day which was very annoying.

Please advise! This is a blocking issue. Thanks.

Comment: Report to Skype ?

Comment: Have you tried to use web.skype.com?

Comment: Don't have the problem on my side: deleted the contact (then got it in history with question mark), used the addContact link from dev.botframework.com and got the contact back again with its green status

Comment: @JustShadow Adding the contact from the web version worked! thanks. I don't know how I got into that situation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As confirmed in comments, trying add/remove bot from web version of Skype works:
https://web.skype.com
So probably that really was a bug of Skype for windows.